# Not understanding a MapReduce NPE

Tags: java, generics, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

Here is the error I receive:

```
    14/02/28 02:52:43 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201402271927_0020_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.init(MapTask.java:843)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.createSortingCollector(MapTask.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.access$100(MapTask.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:584)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
```

I've commented my code out to essentially take in the typical LongWritable and Text and then I just output a constant IntWritable 1 and an empty weather class (custom class):

**Here is my mapper class:**

```
public class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, Weather> {

private IntWritable id = new IntWritable(1);
private Weather we = new Weather();

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    //String s;
    //String line = value.toString();

    //int start[] =   {0,18,31,42,53,64,74,84,88,103};
    //int end[] =     {6,22,33,44,55,66,76,86,93,108};

    //if(line.length() > 108) {
        // create the object to hold our data
        // getStuff()
        // parse the string

        // push the object onto our data structure
        context.write(id, we);
    //}
}
```

**Here is my reducer:**

```
public class Reduce extends Reducer<IntWritable, Weather, IntWritable, Text> {
    private Text text = new Text("one");
    private IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Weather> weather, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        //for(Weather w : weather) {
        //    text.set(w.toString());
        context.write(one, text);
    }
}
```

**Here is my main:**

```
public class Skyline {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        //String s = args[0].length() > 0 ? args[0] : "skyline.in";
        Path input, output;
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        conf.set("io.serializations", "org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.JavaSerialization,"
                + "org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization");
        try {
            input = new Path(args[0]);
        } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            input = new Path("hdfs://localhost/user/cloudera/in/skyline.in");
        }
        try {
            output = new Path(args[1]);
            //FileSystem.getLocal(conf).delete(output, true);
        } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            output = new Path("hdfs://localhost/user/cloudera/out/");
            //FileSystem.getLocal(conf).delete(output, true);
        }

        Job job = new Job(conf, "skyline");

        job.setJarByClass(Skyline.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Weather.class);

        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, input);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, output);
        try {
            job.waitForCompletion(true);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted Exception");
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException");
        }
    }
}
```

**here is a sample of my Weather class:**

```
public class Weather {

private in stationId;

public Weather(){}

public int getStation(){return this.stationID;}
public void setStation(int r){this.stationID = r}
//...24 additional things of ints, doubles and strings
}
```

I'm at my wits end.  At this point I have a shell of a program that does nothing and am still receiving the error.  I've read up on Java Generics, to make sure I'm using them correctly (I think I am), I'm very green to the MapReduce paradigm, but this program is just a shell, modified from the MapReduce tutorial (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html#Walk-through).

Comment: Could you include the definition of your `Weather` class?

Comment: It is a real simple class that has nothing but 25 get/set methods.  No work is done in the constructor.  It is the easiest way to move 25 weather variables from a single station around the program.  See above for the code.

Comment: I'm suspecting you need to implement `org.apache.Hadoop.io.Writable` in your Weather class for this to work.  If you want to pass around non-Writables, you'll have write a whole lot more custom code.

Comment: I just removed the use of the Weather class, so I'm just passing IntWritables around and I still get the same errors, so anywhere you see "weather" replace that with "IntWritable".

Comment: If you're absolutely sure you've removed all uses of Weather and replaced them with IntWritables (including where you set up the job), then I don't have any other ideas, sorry.  The error is clearly thrown when map outputter is being set up.

As a general remedy, I can suggest starting from scratch by following the tutorial to the letter, and if that works, incrementally modify it by introducing custom code.  You may be able to more easily detect where a bug is creeping in.

Comment: Nope, you're right I missed the job configuration class :(.  I just changed that and the job is running.  So I will attempt to implement the writable interface on the Weather class and see if that fixes the problem.  Could you please add the writable implementation as an answer, that if it works, I can accept it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the class that you're using for `map()` output / `reduce()` input, `Weather` does not implement `Writable`.  This will prevent the default `SerializationFactory` from being able to process your values.

The underlying conceptual problem is that Hadoop does not know how to serialize your data type to disc and read it back.  That is a mandatory step, because the data has to be persisted before it can be moved from the map task to a reducer (the two can run on separate nodes, in general).

So what you want to do is implement `Writable` and add serialization routines in your custom data type.

Comment: My weather class implements the writable interface and I have shell functions that the interface requires and it works!  Thank you so much.